# Jquery wordpress content loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I have a problem with a website.
I am new in javascript.
I need to do that when I click on a menu item (wordpress) and then whe window is loaded, automaticaly scroll down to the content(empty) div.
My javascript code not working. What should I do?

My code:

```
<script>
        $(".menu-item").click(function() {
            $( window ).load(function() {
                $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $('.content').offset().top }, 'slow');
            });
        });

</script>
```

The two codes working with alone, but in this version not working.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to StackOverflow!  You can increase the quality of the responses you get by including information about what you've already tried, and what the results were.  Try that here.  What does the code you've included do?  In cases like these, where describing the problem might be difficult, you can clarify things by posting a link to a site like jsfiddle.com, where you've got as close to a working  example of your code as you can get.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know what you exactly want, but first you need to call **window.onload** and then append click event.

Like this:

```
<script>
        $( window ).load(function() {
            $(".menu-item").click(function() {               
                $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $('.content').offset().top }, 'slow');
            });
        });    
</script>
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your answear. the code what you wrote: when you click on a menu-item, that will be scroll down then load the content. i want when i click to a menu item and the content is loaded, then scroll down to the content. understand? sory for my english :/